# Does columns order in multiple columns unique constraint make any difference? Is it justifiable to have duplicate indexes?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, unique-constraint

In "SQL Certified Expert Exam Guide" by Steve O'Hearn I've found this paragraph:

> In the rare instance when you create a composite index along with multiple constraints that call on the same index, a special syntax is required. For example, if we decide to create a composite index on both of our columns in the INVOICES table, we can use this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(
    invoice_id    NUMBER(11),
    invoice_date  DATE,
    CONSTRAINT    un_invoices_invoice_id UNIQUE (invoice_id, invoice_date)
                  USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX ix_invoices
                                      ON invoices(invoice_id, invoice_date)),
    CONSTRAINT    un_invoices_invoice_date UNIQUE (invoice_date, invoice_id)
                  USING INDEX ix_invoices
);
```

And here're my questions:

1. What's the point in creating two unique constraints changing only columns order in declaration?
2. We've create one multiple-column index: "invoice_id" as first column and "invoice_date" as second column. But let's assume that we really often run queries that relate to "invoice_date" itself, without "invoice_id" participation. Would it be a good idea to create second, single column index on "invoice_date"? I know that:

> Because Oracle supports multi-column indexes, it’s easy to accidently create “duplicate” indexes, indexes that **add overhead to DML and do not aid in speeding-up SQL execution**.
>   [[Source]](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_detecting_duplicate_indexes.htm)

and I also know that:

> Thanks to *skip scanning* a WHERE clause that references **any columns within a composite index** may invoke the index in its processing. [Steve O'Hearn]

but also I know that:

> **This isn't quite as beneficial as a simple one-column index**, and its benefit varies, depending on the uniqueness of values in the first column. [Steve O'Hearn]

So let's assume that we rarely use DML commands on this table and let's assume that we relate to both columns in SELECT's WHERE clause as often as to "index_date" or "index_id" separately. Would it be justified, in certain situations, to create two indexes? One, multiple column index, on (index_id, index_date) and second, single column index, on (index_date)?

Comment: A very educational site about indexing: **[Use the index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is:

> Would it be justified, in certain situations, to create two indexes?
>   One, multiple column index, on (index_id, index_date) and second,
>   single column index, on (index_date)?

The answer is "yes".  The first index will be used to satisfy queries with conditions like:

- filtering on `index_id` in the `where` clause
- filtering on `index_id` and `index_date` in the `where` clause
- filtering on `index_id` in the `where` clause and the ordering by `index_date`

The second index would not be used in these circumstance.  It would be used for:

- filtering on `index_date` in the `where` clause

And the first index would *not* be used in this case.

The ordering of columns in indexes is important.  They are used from the left to the right.  So, these two indexes are useful.  However, a third index on `index_id` alone would not be useful, because the first index already takes care of the same situations where that index would be used.

Comment: Oh, I didn't predict this scenario:

"filtering on index_id in the where clause and the ordering by index_date"

Does it mean that instead of creating those two indexes:
(index_id, index_date),
(index_date)

creating those two:
(index_id, index_date),
(index_date, index_id)


also makes sense, if we sometimes filter on index_id and order by index_date and sometimes filter on index_date and order by index_id?

If so, how does optimizer know which one to use when it spots both "index_id" and "index_date" in WHERE clause?

Comment: @r4czek . . . Yes, putting both columns in the index in reverse order could make a lot of sense.  I do not know how Oracle chooses which index when there are multiple "equivalent" choices.

Answer (score 5):

You asked

> "What's the point in creating two unique constraints changing only columns order in declaration?"

There isn't any point.  The order of columns in a composite constraint doesn't make any difference:

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

      COL1 COL
---------- ---
         1 WTF

SQL> create index t23_i on t23(col1, col2);

Index created.

SQL> alter table t23 add constraint t23_uk unique (col1 , col2) using index t23_i
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t23 values (1, 'WTF')
  2  /
insert into t23 values (1, 'WTF')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_UK) violated


SQL> alter table t23 drop  constraint t23_uk
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t23 add constraint t23_uk unique (col2, col1) using index t23_i
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t23 values (1, 'WTF')
  2  /
insert into t23 values (1, 'WTF')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.T23_UK) violated


SQL>
```

That's the problem with exam-crammers: they often just say stuff, without providing explanation or context.

You also asked:

> " Would it be a good idea to create second, single column index on `invoice_date`?"

Without knowing the data it's hard to tell, but I would expect a date column to be less selective than an ID column (especially if the time element is truncated), so generally I would expect an index to built as `(invoice_date, invoice_id)` anyway.  That might allows us to use index compression.

Skip-scanning doesn't quite work as Steve states: it starts by probing the leading edge of the index, but only if the second column in the composite index is referenced in the WHERE clause.  The optimizer might choose a Full Fast Index Scan for searching on third columns or lower.  Also it won't choose a Skip Scan path if the leading edge has too many distinct values: another good reason for leading with columns of low selectively.

So, this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think it does convey an important point: there are no universal rules governing creating indexes for performance.  We need to understand the profile of the data - its values distribution and volumes - and also the most important queries which will use the table.